# @Html.CheckBoxFor with string in for-loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am building a dynamic form in MVC. All (about 50) questions and provided answers are stored in the database.
I use a for-loop to dynamically populate the view with the questions, which works fine for @HtmlEditorFor but not where I need to use checkboxes. Since the form is dynamic the answer-property is always a string. I want to store a 0 or 1 as the answer in the database to the checkbox-questions.
For the @HtmlCheckBoxFor I get an error that says:

> "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single->dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

```
@for (int i = startValue; i < maxValue; i++) {

<tr>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(r => r.Questions[i].QuestionText)</td>

<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(r => r.Questions[i].Answer == "1")</td>

</tr>
startValue++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this issue try to decrease the length of QuestionText 
 :

```
@for (int i = startValue; i < maxValue; i++) {

<tr>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(r => r.Questions[i].QuestionText.Substring(0,100) )</td>

<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(r => r.Questions[i].Answer == "1")</td>

</tr>
startValue++;
}
```

or you can solve your problem with this solution :

```
   @for (int i = startValue; i < maxValue; i++) {

    <tr>
    <td> @Questions[i].QuestionText </td>

    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(r => r.Questions[i].Answer == "1")</td>

    </tr>
    startValue++;
    }
```

i hope that this solution can help you